# Count number of occurrences of a column in another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a set of references (serialized arrays) and want to count the number of occurences. For example my table looks like

```
ID       type       reference
206     "apple"     ""
211     "fruits"    "a:1:{i:0;s:3:"206";}"
212     "apple"     ""
214     "fruits"    "a:1:{i:0;s:3:"212";}"
217     "apple"     ""
359     "fruits"    "a:1:{i:0;s:3:"206";i:1;s:3:"360";}"
360     "apple"     ""
```

Now I want to count how often an ID from apple is referenced in fruits, such that my final table should look like this

```
ID     type    count
206   "apple"   2
212   "apple"   1
217   "apple"   0
360   "apple"   1
```

My first idea was to count the number of apperances of the string ':"$ID";' (i.e. ':"206";'), but I dont know how to do this for each ID and furthermore I dont know exactly if this would be save, since these are serialized arrays.

Is there any way to do this with mysql?

Comment: Is there any good reason to store the data that way? Or can you change it?

Comment: Actually this is a multiselect field, which gets stored this way in the database. Unfortunately I cant change it...

Comment: What happens if you change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the given data:

```sql
select t1.ID, t1.type, count(t2.type) as `count`
from table1 t1
left join table1 t2
  on  t2.type = 'fruits'
  and t2.reference like concat('%"', t1.ID, '"%')
where t1.`type` <> 'fruits'
group by t1.ID, t1.type;
```

Result:

```sql
|  ID |  type | count |
|-----|-------|-------|
| 206 | apple |     2 |
| 212 | apple |     1 |
| 217 | apple |     0 |
| 360 | apple |     1 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a790/4

There are many crazy things you can do with SQL - but it doesn't mean that you should.